# Is there anyway for Tikz-cd to point at the beginning of a node instead of the middle

Tags: beamer, tikz-cd

This code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile, t]{My slides}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
\text{The starting point}
\arrow{d} \\ 
\text{first node}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Generates

[image]

Is it possible to point at the beginning instead of the center like this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with anchors:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile, t]{My slides}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
\text{The starting point}
\arrow[end anchor=north west]{d} \\ 
|[anchor=real west]|\text{first node}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you may just use some cheap trick.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile, t]{My slides}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
\text{The starting point}
\arrow{d} \\ 
\phantom{\text{first nod}}\text{first node}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile, t]{My slides}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
\text{The starting point}
\arrow{d} \\ 
|[text width={1.88*width("first node")},align=right]|\text{first node}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like this hack, even though the Latex code doesn't really make sense with the stuff in vphantom. But at least I will be the only one to ever use it